# Send (relatively large amount of) data to PHP database with JS event

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am new to PHP, and from what I understand, you can't call a php function with JS. I want to send a name, address, and a very long string for pizza orders somehow. Here is my PHP code so far

```
<?php

    $UNAME = 'root';
    $PWORD = 'password';
    $DATABASENAME = 'pizza_orders';
    $TABLENAME = 'orders';

    $pizzaOrderTable = 
        mysql_connect('localhost', $UNAME, $PWORD) 
        or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($DATABASENAME, $pizzaOrderTable);

    function sendOrder($name, $address, $pizzas) {
        global $TABLENAME, $toInsert, $pizzaOrderTable;

        $toInsert = "INSERT INTO $TABLENAME  
            (Name, Address, Pizzas) 
            VALUES('$name', '$address', '$pizzas')";

        mysql_query($toInsert, $pizzaOrderTable);

        echo $toInsert;
    }

    sendOrder('Dylan', '13 Bla St', 'lots of stuff here ...............');

?>
```

I want to send order. The name, address and pizzas strings I calculate through JavaScript (I did this before learning PHP). The pizzas string is far too long to add to a link. If it helps, I have been saving the data to a json file and saving it as a temp file client-side.

How would I send the order?

Comment: im guessing the answer is AJAX

Comment: "The pizzas string is far too long to add to a link".. why don't you use use an html form, you just put your info in hidden fields, and leave visible the submit button only. You can even change the view of the button to look like a link or whatever you want it to look like.

Comment: The name and address I can use a form with, but the pizza string is created using Javascript. And the Ajax, could you point me towards something to read that is related to this situation?